# jQuery Hide/Show with Slide on Hover... better way to do this?

Tags: jquery, animation, hover

Basically having some trouble with using Hover to hide or show an item.

The idea is simple, on hover show a div.  When no longer hovering, hide it.  Problem is if the mouse hovers over the div and leaves too quickly, the show/hide div will stay visible.  I'm hoping this is something easily remedied and not a typical problem with the hover event.

```
 jQuery
 (
   function() 
   {
     jQuery(".slideDiv").hide();

     jQuery(".mainDiv").hover
     (
       function() 
       {
         var children = jQuery(this).children(".slideDiv");

         if (children.is(":hidden")) 
         {
           children.show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 100);
         }
       },
       function() 
       {
          var children = jQuery(this).children(".slideDiv");
          children.hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 100);
       }
     );
   }
 );
```

Styles look like:

```
 .mainDiv
 {
   margin:5px;
   height:200px;
 }

 .slideDiv
 {
   background-color:Teal;
   float:left;
   height:200px;
   position:absolute;
   z-index:100;
 }
```

And markup

```
    <div class="mainDiv">
        <div class="showDiv">
            Hover me
        </div>
        <div class="slideDiv">
            Do you see me?
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="mainDiv">
        <div class="showDiv">
            Hover me too
        </div>
        <div class="slideDiv">
            Do you see me now?
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin. This avoids anything being shown if the user simply passes the mouse over the elements, and avoids an unsightly chain of animations.

Comment: +1 for exposing me to the hoverIntent plugin, this is the reason I come here and browse around the jQuery threads.. I pick up so many cool tricks.

Comment: This looks great, i'll use this plugin!

Answer (score 6):

I tried your script and it did as you described. I tried removing the children.is(":hidden") from your script, but the problem still occurred.

When I rewrote it the script the div never stays visible. So, it appears that the problem is with using jQuery's *children* instead of *find* to get to the object:

Still has problems:

```
 jQuery (
   function(){
     jQuery(".slideDiv").hide();
     jQuery(".mainDiv").hover (
       function() {
         $(this).children(".slideDiv").show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 100);
       },function(){
         $(this).children(".slideDiv").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 100);
       }
     );
   }
 );
```

Works as intended:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.slideDiv').hide();
   $('.mainDiv').hover(
     function(){
       $(this).find('.slideDiv').show('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 100)
     },
     function(){
       $(this).find('.slideDiv').hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 100)
     }
   )
 })
```

And yes, The hoverIntent plugin is nice :P