# title popups automatically without delay

Tags: javascript, html, css

is there any chance to do a js onclick function, that if someone will click on that icon automatically the title text will be shown, or just when someone moves mouse over it, title will be shown without any delay? Right now title for element comes out after 1 sec.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change how fast "title" attribute's tooltip appears](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150796/change-how-fast-title-attributes-tooltip-appears)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to override the default browser behaviour of how it displays tooltips containing the `title` attribute text, but you could follow the steps on this other question to show and hide a `div` containing the relevant text (the approach uses jQuery and deals with hover, but adding a `click` handler isn't much of a stretch).

[jQuery Hide/Show with Slide on Hover... better way to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105783/jquery-hide-show-with-slide-on-hover-better-way-to-do-this/1200834#1200834)

Answer (score 14):

you can try this, pure css, without js:

HTML:

```
<div class="hover">
    Hover Me
    <div class="tooltip">
        Tooltip goes here
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.hover{
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    width:150px;
    position:relative;
}

.tooltip{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding:5px;
    top:-10px;
    left:200px;
    width: 300px;
}

.hover:hover .tooltip{
    display:block;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kamil335/qGTUc/

Answer (score 9):

[I *just* answered the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928053/how-to-keep-the-title-attribute-value-visable-after-clicking/7928116#7928116)

You'll have to create your own tooltip.  You don't need JavaScript, pure CSS is enough:

```css
.tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: #ffe;
    border: 1px solid #eed;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}
:hover + .tooltip {
    display: block;
}
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
```

```html
<div>Hover for tooltip</div>
<span class="tooltip">Tooltip text goes here</span>
```

[jsfiddle.net/v655C](http://jsfiddle.net/v655C/)