# Change how fast "title" attribute's tooltip appears

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to change how fast the tooltip from an element's "title" attribute? I'd like it if the tooltip appeared immediately, but it seems to take a few seconds to appear.

Comment: Would that not be determined by the operating system and/or web-browser?  Unless you implement your own dynamic tooltip like [this](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/dhtmltooltip.htm) (but less hideous) :)

Comment: Definitely this feature shoud be requested to be added in the html/css standards.

Comment: it's pretty incredible going into 2024 this is not a thing just three features (color, time delay, size) would be enough to eliminate third party solutions and greatly expand HTML5 nobody Likes these tooltip libraries. People want quick, simple, functional and they don't want to write code when they should not have too. if we could control Color, Time Delay, and Font and you would see  all but two or three tooltip libraries dissapear. dozens of tooltip libraries dissappear.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

No, there's no way. The `title` attribute is implemented in a browser dependent fashion. For example I remember differences between IE and FF when using `\r\n` inside it.

[Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) explain the limits and functionality well.

If you want customization you may take a look at third party plugins such as [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) which mimic it using divs and stuff and provide you full control.

Comment: If you are using Foundation, they have a pretty good tooltip component:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tooltips.html

Comment: Does anyone else think it is kinda crazy there isn't a built-in option to change the delay of a title element? Seems like it would be a fairly easy option for browsers to add. Something like title-delay="0" (0 ms) or title-delay="5000" (5000 ms)

Comment: The `qTip2` link is broken.

Answer (score 33):

You could use jqueryUI as suggested. An example of controlling the duration on the show property:

```
$( ".selector" ).tooltip({ show: { effect: "blind", duration: 800 } });
```

Answer (score 28):

Unfortunately, there is **no** way to do this yet,

so I am using the following methods to help. (*No dependencies required*)

```html
<style>
  [title] {
    position: relative;
  }

  [title]:after {
    content: attr(title);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 100%; /* put it on the top */
    background-color: yellow;
    width: max-content;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.75s ease-in-out; /*  Change the time to meet your requirements. */
  }

  [title]:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
  }
</style>

<div style="min-height:5rem"></div>
<div style="min-width: 5rem; border: 2px solid red;" title="hello world">my div</div>
<button title="for debug">button</button>
```

If you don't want the [title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) to conflict with it, you can use [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) <sup>[w3school.data-*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)</sup> help you, for example.

```html
<style>
  [data-tooltip] {
    position: relative;
  }

  [data-tooltip]:after {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 100%; /* put it on the top */
    background-color: yellow;
    width: max-content;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.75s ease-in-out;
  }

  [data-tooltip]:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  div[data-tooltip]:after {
    left: 5px!important;
  }
</style>

<div style="min-height:5rem"></div>
<div style="min-width: 5rem; border: 2px solid red;" data-tooltip="hello world">my div</div>
<button data-tooltip="for debug">button</button>
<button title="for debug">title only</button>
<button data-tooltip="my tool tip msg" title="my title msg">title and tooltip</button>
```

below link may help you too.

- [fade in and out on simple css tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21138554/9935654)

Comment: Whoaa...nice trick there.

Comment: I used `display: none` instead of `opacity: 0`. I prefer it because it makes the hidden tooltip insensitive to hovering. I just want hovering the element itself to make the tooltip appear.

Answer (score 19):

[Jquery UI tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) is extremely simple and customizable: Just [download](http://jqueryui.com/download/) or [include](https://code.jquery.com/ui/) jquery UI in your page.

If you want all the tooltips of your page to show immediately at hover, just use this:

```
$(document).tooltip({show: null});
```

Note that this applies to all elements that have a 'title' attribute.
You can modify the selector to affect only a class, and set custom speed or effect:

```
$('.yourClass').tooltip({show: {effect:"none", delay:0}});
```

Answer (score 7):

It isn't possible to change how fast default browser's tooltip appear, but you can use one of the tooltip plugins (here is few: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/ ) where you can customise lot's of things, including delay.

Comment: Couldn't find any tooltip plugin in the link provided.

Comment: yeah - links die, however.. google:  stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins  and a load of similar pages pop up :-)

Answer (score 3):

TippyJS has a billion customization options.

[image: Example TippyJS tooltip]

https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs

https://github.com/atomiks/tippyjs