# Remove tooltip delay for HTML element

Tags: css, html

**@Mukyuu helpfully flagged a duplicate question, but it is quite old and the correct answer in 2019 may be very different. For instance, @Andy Hoffman has suggested a workaround that was not viable years ago.**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811538/how-to-delay-basic-html-tooltip) is similar, but not the same.

Our web page contains multiple tooltips. There's a noticeable 1-2 second lag before the first tooltip appears (on Chrome). After this first one appears, subsequent tooltips appear nearly instantly as you hover over other elements.

To be clear, tooltip refers to the value in the `title` attribute of an element like this:

```html
<input type="button" title="Click" value="My Button">
```

Is there a way to make all tooltips appear instantly?

Comment: @Mukyuu given the age of the post and answers from that question, what's the protocol for asking if there's an updated answer to the question?

Comment: If you think a duplicate question deserves fresh attention, then you can offer a bounty on it instead of duplicating it.

Answer (score 9):

You can use an element's pseudo [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) to display a tooltip on hover. Note, pseudo content does not work with `input`s but *does* work with `button`, as in the following example.

```css
.my-button {
  position: relative;
}

.my-button:hover::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  bottom: -2.5em;
  right: -1em;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: .25em .5em;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" title="Click" value="My Button">

<button class="my-button" data-tooltip="Click">My Button</button>
```

**Update**

As a workaround for `input`, include a wrapper `div`, and use the data attribute of that `div` instead of the child `input`.

```css
.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.input-wrapper:hover::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  bottom: -2.5em;
  right: -1em;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: .25em .5em;
  font-size: .8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper" data-tooltip="Click">
  <input type="button" value="My Button">
</div>
```

Comment: what if we need a solution compatible with inputs? stuck with `title` attribute and the lag?

Comment: this is a cool trick btw to use `attr()` in the content property! is this widely supported? thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Crashalot Support for `attr()` is IE8+.

Comment: For others who are curious, according to caniuse.com: "... attr() is supported for effectively all browsers for the content property..."