# How to make the tooltip to show immediately for some elements in JavaScript or CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to show a tool tip immediately for some elements? I have a few help icons and button that I want to show the tooltip immediately as the mouse moves over them. Is there CSS to do this?

```css
.showTooltip {
   background-color: yellow;
   padding:8px;
   top: 20px;
   left: 20px;
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0 auto;
   border: 2px solid lightgrey;
   cursor: pointer;
   font-family: system, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="showTooltip" title="I am a tooltip">
 Hover over me and a tool tip appears after a few seconds
</div>
```

Here is a test using after class

```css
.showTooltip {
   background-color: yellow;
   padding:8px;
   top: 20px;
   left: 20px;
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0 auto;
   border: 2px solid lightgrey;
   cursor: pointer;
   font-family: system, sans-serif;
}

.showTooltip:hover::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(data-tip);
  top: 3.5em;
  left: 2em;
  background-color: #585858;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: .25em .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="showTooltip" data-tip="I am a tool tip">
 Hover over me and a tool tip appears immediately
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55468858/remove-tooltip-delay-for-html-element

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150796/change-how-fast-title-attributes-tooltip-appears

Comment: @somebodysomewhere I got it to work sortof. It works in the example here but doesn't work in my project using attr(data-tooltip). If I type my own text it works but with attr() it's blank. My environment might not support content style.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Which platform are you using `attr()` on? [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=attr()) mentioned that it's supported in almost all platforms.

Comment: @Richard It's a hybrid system at work that doesn't support all web technologies. I've posted to the developers to see if `attr()` is supported. The example works here but the same example doesn't work on the platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```css
    
        .showTooltip {
          background-color: yellow;
          padding:8px;
          top: 20px;
          left: 20px;
          position: absolute;
          margin: 0 auto;
          border: 2px solid lightgrey;
          cursor: pointer;
          font-family: system, sans-serif;
        }
    
        .showTooltip:hover::after {
          position: absolute;
          content: attr(data-tooltip);
          bottom: -2.5em;
          right: -1em;
          background-color: #333;
          color: white;
          padding: .25em .5em;
          font-size: .8em;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="showTooltip" data-tooltip="I am a tooltip">
    Hover over me and a tool tip appears after a few seconds
    </div>
```