# Delay turbo frame load via scss

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, sass

I have the following scss thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811538/how-to-delay-basic-html-tooltip):

```scss
     .hoverWrapper {
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
    
        &:hover #hoverContent {
            display:inline-block;
            visibility: visible;
            animation: tooltipkeys 0.5s 1; //here just change the 1s to you desired delay time!
            opacity: 1;
        }
          
          @-webkit-keyframes tooltipkeys {
            0% {
              opacity: 0;
            }
            75% {
              opacity: 0;
            }
            100% {
              opacity: 1;
            }
          }
          
          @-moz-keyframes tooltipkeys {
            0% {
              opacity: 0;
            }
            75% {
              opacity: 0;
            }
            100% {
              opacity: 1;
            }
          }
          
          @-o-keyframes tooltipkeys {
            0% {
              opacity: 0;
            }
            75% {
              opacity: 0;
            }
            100% {
              opacity: 1;
            }
          }
          
          @keyframes tooltipkeys {
            0% {
              opacity: 0;
            }
            75% {
              opacity: 0;
            }
            100% {
              opacity: 1;
            }
          }
        }
    
    
    #hoverContent {
        display: none;
        text-align: center;
        min-width: 15rem;
        top: -20px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
        color: var(--color-dark);
        background-color: var(--color-white);
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: var(--font-size-s);
        border-radius: var(--border-radius);
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 99999999;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        box-shadow: var(--shadow-back);
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 1s;
    
        i {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -12px;
            width: 24px;
            height: 12px;
            overflow: hidden;
    
            &::after {
                position: absolute;
                width: 12px;
                height: 12px;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(45deg);
                background-color: var(--color-white);
                box-shadow: var(--shadow-back);
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="hoverWrapper">
  <span role="button" aria-describedby="id">
    <div class="card card--info">
        cool code block here
    </div>
  </span>
  <div id="hoverContent">
    <turbo-frame id="id" target="_top" role="tooltip" loading="lazy" src="src stuff">
      Loading...
    </turbo-frame>
  </div>
</div>
```

The delay works and the `hoverContent` does not appear for the set time in animation. However, the `turboframe` fires as soon as the mouse hovers over `hoverContent`. The whole point of the delayed `hoverContent` was to prevent the `turboframe` from firing until the `hoverContent` was in view.

I understand that with `loading=lazy` the turbo frame will not load until it is in view. I would think this approach would prevent the `turboframe` from being in view. But it does not.

Reason:
The reason I want the delay is because a user could roam around the page hovering over multiple tabs, each which have lazy load, I'm trying to prevent those query's unless the user really wants to see them, i.e. mouse over a tab for 1-2s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're setting `display: inline-block` on *hover* which triggers the lazy loading. `opacity` and `visibility` don't affect the layout so they have no effect on the lazy loading.

Basically, lazy loading is triggered if `turbo-frame` overlaps the viewport. Even if it's invisible or transparent.

To solve it, you have to remove any overlap, just make a `0px` box:

```js
// fake the turbo-frame lazy loading. ignore this part
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  const entry = entries[0];
  if (!entry.target.hasAttribute("complete") && entry.isIntersecting) {
    console.log("lazy load triggered. wait for it...");
    entry.target.setAttribute("complete", "");
    entry.target.innerHTML = "Loaded";
  }
}, {
  threshold: 1,
});
observer.observe(document.querySelector("[loading=lazy]"));
```

```css
.hoverWrapper:hover #hoverContent {
  animation: tooltipkeys 2s forwards;
}

#hoverContent {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes tooltipkeys {
  0%   { opacity: 0 }
  75%  { opacity: 0 }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverWrapper">
  <span> hover me </span>
  <div id="hoverContent">
    <turbo-frame id="frame_id" loading="lazy" src="/url">
      Loading...
    </turbo-frame>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Actual *turbo* logic is very simple for this:
*https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/blob/v7.3.0/src/observers/appearance_observer.ts#L33*

*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API*

Comment: Thanks that was it. Also thanks for the links honestly did not know about that.