# Is it possible to show text instead of tooltip in image map?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website. I am using "Image Mapper" plugin to show names of different block of books in library.
It show tooltips like this one:
http://workbench.altervista.org/1.jpg

But I want to make text visible on highlighted area.
This should look like this:
http://workbench.altervista.org/2.jpg

Also tooltip becomes visible after 1-2 seconds. I want to show name immediately.

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do what you want with Image Mapper, as it simply creates a map on the image. A map is an area that you associates with an image, so the browser may consider that area clickable.

What you want could be done using absolute positioned links, but I could not find any wordpress plugin to help you with that.

Comment: Ok. Can we speed up tooltip so that it is shown immediately?

Comment: This reply should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150796/change-how-fast-title-attributes-tooltip-appears Ah, please mark this question as answered if my response satisfied you! Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Last Question: Can we add CSS style to normal tooltip?

Comment: I would say no, but this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927640/styling-native-tooltip-from-title-tooltip-text