# Change delay of showing tooltip title of icon

Tags: html, css

I have this piece of html:

```
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment" title="Hello"></i>
```

This displays comment icon from [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/comment/). When I hoover over this icon, tooltip with text `Hello` is displayed. There is a delay between hoovering over icon and displaying the text. How do I change length of this delay? To be more specific, I would like to display title instantly.

I am aware, that this could be achieved by writing my own tooltip. However, I would like to avoid it and (if possible) use native solution.

Comment: It is not possible using native solution. You will have to implement it or use those provided by frameworks like Bootstrap. Have a look at this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150796/change-how-fast-title-attributes-tooltip-appears](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150796/change-how-fast-title-attributes-tooltip-appears)

Comment: There is a way for the user to change the tooltip delay browser-wide, at least in Mozilla browsers. Set the _about:config_ entry `ui.tooltipDelay` to the time in milliseconds you want. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Preference_reference/ui.tooltipDelay). Not sure if Chrome has a similar setting.