# Looking for options on how to display info alert when mouse highlights link

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a relatively simple site that displays links my team and I use. One of the requirements is to display note information when a user has their mouse cursor over any of the links. I understand that the easiest method is simply not list the link if no one's using it, but the team insists on posting the URL on this site for archival reasons. They may also come back to the link and use it again in their environment(s).

Consider this link:

```
<a href="www.footester.com/foofootestest">Test Environment #1</a>
```

I want this alert (below) to become displayed when the mouse cursor is hovering over the link:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <strong>Note: The testers are not using this link as a part of their test environment!</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

If there are any other suggestions on other methods to accomplish this, I'd love to hear.

Comment: have a look at [JavaScript's `addEventListener` function with `mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) event, or if you're using jQuery library (basically a JavaScript framework) you could make use of its [`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) function.

Comment: You can use a `a ~ div` css rule: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ww6wqv7q/

Comment: you may want to accept one of the answers as the correct one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your link and alert each an `id` so you can target it with JavaScript, also hide your alert by default, something like this:

```
<a id="testenv" href="www.footester.com/foofootestest">Test Environment #1</a>

<div id="testalert" style="display:none" class="alert alert-info">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Then use JavaScript to fire the `mouseover` event when the link is hovered like this:

```
var testenv = document.getElementById("testenv"),
    testalert = document.getElementById("testalert");

testenv.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
    testalert.style.display = "block";
}, false);
```

Just for fun you could also add a `mouseout` event making the alert disappear again when the mouse gets off the link (not hovered anymore):

```
testenv.addEventListener("mouseout", function( event ) {
    testalert.style.display = "none";
}, false);
```

Here is the full code inside a code snippet block:

```js
var testenv = document.getElementById("testenv"),
    testalert = document.getElementById("testalert");

testenv.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
    testalert.style.display = "block";
}, false);

testenv.addEventListener("mouseout", function( event ) {
    testalert.style.display = "none";
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a id="testenv" href="www.footester.com/foofootestest">Test Environment #1</a>

<div class="container">
  <div id="testalert" style="display:none" class="alert alert-info">
    <strong>Note: The testers are not using this link as a part of their test environment!</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here you can play with this code on bootply (the bootstrap testing sandbox): http://www.bootply.com/TfrhmIbqq8

Answer (score 2):

It may be very basic, but did you consider to try:

```html
<a href="www.footester.com/foofootestest" title="Note: The testers are not using this link as a part of their test environment!">Test Environment #1</a>
```

The advantage is that you'll not be **alerted** on any link you hover, But receives a note.

Comment: I did consider this approach before, and I thank you for bringing it up. The only issue (and I'm hoping either you or someone would know) I have with this is that the title appears fractions of a second too long. Is it possible to make the title pop up faster, like even more nearly instant? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, no. There is no way to make the title attribute appear faster: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9150826/5884242

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar for a personal project I am working on, and used the [Bootstrap Popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) plugin for this type of display. With a little jQuery, it's fairly simple to hook it up to the mouseover event and have the popover even follow your cursor around on the note.

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bwolfing/nf5d5xm9/1/) as an example! :D

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function onRowMouseLeave(e)
  {
    $(e.target).popover("hide");
  }

  function onRowMouseMove(e)
  {
          $(e.target).popover("show");
          // Magic numbers to offset from cursor slightly and prevent popover from flashing as much
          $(".popover").css({ top: e.pageY - 14, left: e.pageX + 6 }).find(".arrow").css("top", "14px");
  }
  
  
 $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover({
       animation: false,
        container: "body",
        html: true,
        placement: "right", 
        trigger: "manual",
      }).on("mousemove", "", onRowMouseMove)
   .on("mouseleave", "", onRowMouseLeave);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" data-content="<div class='alert alert-danger'>Here is the note to display</div>">
    Content I want to hover
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work but you have to add the alert container below every link

```css
a {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.alert {
  display: none;
}
a:hover + .container .alert {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="www.footester.com/foofootestest">Test Environment #1</a>
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <strong>Note: The testers are not using this link as a part of their test environment!</strong>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="www.footester.com/foofootestest">Test Environment #1</a>
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <strong>Note: The testers are not using this link as a part of their test environment!</strong>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="www.footester.com/foofootestest">This does not get Alert</a>
<a href="www.footester.com/foofootestest">Test Environment #1</a>
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <strong>Note: The testers are not using this link as a part of their test environment!</strong>
  </div>
</div>
```