# Showing HTML title attribute faster

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to reduce the delay on the display of the HTML title attribute?

Comment: Do you meathead title of the page? Or the title displayed on the rollover effect?

Comment: see if the suggestion given on this thread helps. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7928243/276263

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you implement your own tooltip mechanism you can freely adjust the time it takes to show up. There is no way to modify the native tooltip.

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering if there was a way of modifying the native tooltip. I guess not.

Comment: Bootstrap has some interesting tooltips. getbootstrap.com

Answer (score 0):

Assume there was no delay, and when you move the mouse over the page ,if every element that you passed across instantly popped up a title tooltip, how confusing it would be.I dont think ew can remove that delay.

There are many jquery apis available, which can be used as a replacement for tooltip functionality.
eg:qtip